# Hook and modify an email being sent by Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, email, plugin

I am trying to find a way to modify my email letter content before sending it. 
I want to be able to modify any email being sent by Magento.

For instance I need to achieve the following.

1. Be notified when any email is sent
2. In case an email is sent to a specific user group do some action
3. Otherwise leave it without any changes

What is the right way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you want for which email?

Comment: For any email being sent in the system

Answer (score 2):

All E-mails sent through Magento are sent through an instance of the `Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface` class. So you could write a plugin for that class

**etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface">
    <plugin name="my_mail_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Mail\Transport"/>
</type>
```

**Vendor/Module/Mail/Transport.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Mail;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface as Subject;

class Transport {
    public function beforeSendMessage(Subject $subject) {
         /** @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface $message */
         $message = $subject->getMessage();
         // do whatever you want before the mail is sent. 
         // The $message variable contains an object of the mail to be sent
         return []; // The plugin's parent function contains no parameters
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I check what we have in $message?

Comment: It's an instance of \Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface. Just call the functions available inside it

Comment: I am trying 
$message = $subject->getMessage()->getBody();
$message = str_replace("post@example.no","hello@hello.no",$message); $subject->getMessage()->setBody($message);
but it doesnt seem to be working.. I tried all 3 method before, after and around